# Use R to to test hypothesis of correlation = .5

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to make a hypothesis test for my correlation H0: r= .5, H1: R != .5. R works fine for testing the hypothesis H0: r= 0. I looked online to see if any parameter in "cor.test" allowed me to change the hypothesis test but it is not available.

> cor.test(x, y,
>            alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),
>            method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"),
>            exact = NULL, conf.level = 0.95, continuity = FALSE, ...)

Here is my code

```
> avgTemp
 [1] 21 24 32 47 50 59 68 74 62 50 41 30
> usage
 [1] 185.79 214.47 288.03 424.84 454.68 539.03 621.55 675.06 562.03 452.93
[11] 369.95 273.98
> cor.test (avgTemp,usage)

        Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  avgTemp and usage
t = 272.255, df = 10, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.9997509 0.9999817
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.9999326
```

Again, everything is working fine. I just don't know how to make my hypothesis test H0: r=.5

Thanks !

Comment: There's a statistical transformation you can apply: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14222/36229

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing if the null value is inside the confidence interval is equivalent to a test of hypothesis (sometimes with a little different assumptions).  Since 0.5 is clearly outside of the confidence interval shown above that is equivalent to rejecting the null hypothesis that the true correlation is 0.5 at a 2-sided alpha level of 0.05.

Another option (which gives you more control of the assumptions) is to simulate a large number of datasets that have the same general properties as your original data (means, standard deviations) and the null value for the correlation (see the `mvrnorm` function in the MASS package), then compute the correlation for each of the simulated datasets.  Compare the correlation from your data to the simulated correlations, your p-value is the proportion of simulated correlations that are more extreme than the observed one.